# Set a note field size in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote a small script to get together all values from cells(except column one) of a given row and put them as a note in the first column cell of the row. If there is a lot of text the default note field size needs to be adjusted manually. Example is on the picture. I couldn't find any methods to change the note field size in GAS documentation. Couldn't find any related answers on SO. So I'm guessing that this is not possible at the moment? If possible, I'd like to know how to do this.

```
var activeFile = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var firstSheet = activeFile.getSheets()[0];
var fullRange = firstSheet.getDataRange();
var numRows = fullRange.getNumRows();
var numColumns = fullRange.getNumColumns();


function onEdit(e) {
    row = e.range.getRow();
    writeNote(row)
};


function addNotes() {
    for (var row = 1; row <= numRows; row++) {
        writeNote(row)
    };
};


function writeNote(row) {
    for (var col = 1; col <= numColumns; col++) {
        currentCell = fullRange.getCell(row,col);
        if (col === 1) { 
            firstColCell = currentCell;
            var noteText = '';
        } else {
            cellValue = currentCell.getValue();
            if (cellValue) {
                noteText += `${cellValue}\n\n`;
            }
        };
    };
    firstColCell.setNote(noteText);
};
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest you to search the Google Apps Script issue tracker too, maybe someone already make a feature request there about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments as of right now this is not supported.

You could try to file a *Feature Request* in [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) and see if they can get it implemented.